# How do i hide the selected item of spinner

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-spinner

I have a spinner on right side of action bar, and i am using a background draw-able for my spinner. when i click on that draw-able, drop-down list appears with spinner items, and when i select a spinner item, it starts showing at the action bar, i don't want it to show there at the title bar. how can i do that.
Below is the code for my spinner

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/planets_spinner"
    android:layout_width="40sp"
    android:layout_height="35sp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/arrow"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

I have a spinner like this

[image]

On Item selection, i want it to be like this

[image]

but the selected item's name keeps on appearing like this

[image]

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Could you post a screenshot of how it looks now and point out what you want to change?

Comment: Pictures have been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with the spinner adapter, changing the text of the spinner item when it is selected to be blank, and restoring it once it is unselected. This isn't the most graceful solution, but it will give you what you want.